# Space after h1 text

Tags: html, css

I have two h1 side by side and I want a space between the two textes.I tried it with just adding space with the spacebar, but it doesn´t work.

```css
header div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div>
      <h1 id="heading1">Hello my name is </h1>
      <h1 id="heading2"> Paul</h1>
   </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Yeas, but I want the two seperate h1 to be side by side as they are only one h1. But when I do so with display: flex, there is no space between the "Hello my name is" and "Paul". So it´s like "Hello my name isPaul" but I want ot to be like "Hello my name is Paul". Do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`&nbsp;`](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/html-space-how-to-add-a-non-breaking-space-with-the-nbsp-character-entity/)
It's a dedicated HTML character attributed to "space".

**Example:**

```
<div>
  <h1>Hello my name is</h1>&nbsp;
  <h1>Paul</h1>
</div>
```

You can also put it inside of HTML tags, like the `<h1>`, but I personally prefer it outside of it.
I also personally prefer using `&nbsp;` in general since it's a more explicit way to symbolize "space", whereas implicit spaces (`" "`) sometimes get "lost in translation", so to speak..

Answer (score 0):

If you use flex you need to read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/flex)https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/flex

and understand how the layout works. In your case, the `div` take 100% of the width and each `h1` is align left by default. You can set

`justify-content: space-between;` on the div by example, for more see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

Comment: Please add a relevant code snippet or add the answer as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Remember `h1` is a block level element. It will always be in one line. To bring them in same line, change display to `inline-block` like so.

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hello my name is</h1>&nbsp
  <h1>Paul</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I´m an absolute beginner! How can I increase the space between "is" and "Paul"?

Comment: you can do so by setting margin: 0 10px; where 0 is the margin-top and margin-bottom. And 10px is margin-left and margin-right  Also mark it as answered if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it. One of them is:

```css
#header {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1 id="heading1">Hello my name is </h1>
  <h1 id="heading2">Paul</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

trying adding a margin to one of your h1. And please don't use two h1 on a single page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display two `h1` elements in the same line, but color them different or anything like that, just use one `h1` element and a `span` element. Per defintion, every html-page should just have one `h1` element, because it should be used as a page-title.

Also, if you dont need the id's for js or something else, just select them via css.

**Here's a full example:**

```css
#heading span:nth-child(1) {
   color: green;
}

#heading span:nth-child(2) {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div>
        <h1 id="heading">
           <span id="first_heading">Hello my name is </span>
           <span id="second_heading">Paul</span>
        </h1>
    </div>
</header>
```